# type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, datetime, timestamp

I have a type mismatch when I am getting a Timestamp data element from a Firestore document and then try to convert it to a DateTime type and put it in a TextEditingController. I am trying to populate an app form with the data from the firestore document.

Here is a screenshot of the screen:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to convert and assign the data:

```
var dtDate = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(currentEvent.get('eventDate'));
      eventDateController.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dtDate).toString();
```

On the same page I grab the date and time from a datepicker plugin using this code (which works):

```
if (_date != null && _date != _datePicked) {
                        setState(() {
                          eventDateController.text =
                              DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(_datePicked!);
                          eventProvider.changeeventdate(_datePicked);
                          _selectedDate = _datePicked;
                          //DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(_date));
                        });
                      }


This is the code for getting the time:
TimeOfDay _timePicked = await (showTimePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialTime: new TimeOfDay.now()) as FutureOr<TimeOfDay>);
                    _dt = DateTime(_selectedDate!.year, _selectedDate!.month, _selectedDate!.day, _timePicked.hour, _timePicked.minute);
                    //if (_timePicked != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        eventStartTimeController.text = dateFormat.format(_dt); //_timePicked.format(context);
                        eventProvider.changeeventstarttime(_dt);
                      });
                    //}
                  },
```

This is the error I am getting:

type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you check `currentEvent.get('eventDate')` is `DateTime` or `TimeStamp`?

Comment: It is a Timestamp since it is coming from a Firestore document.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out with help from s couple of other posts. This is the answer:

```
eventDateController.text = DateFormat('EE MMddyyyy').format(currentEvent['eventDate'].toDate());
```